# Where to find the default context processors in django 1.10?

Tags: django

When adding a context processor, you seem to need to add the default context processors as well, else you won't have for example the `auth` context processors. But in django 1.10, the documentation for the context processors doesn't contain the default list anymore, except on the pages for migrating from old `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` to the new `TEMPLATES` setting.

Where can i find a official list of context processors for default projects? Or is there some option to append just the own context processor, without touching the default list?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official list of Django's 1.10 [built-in template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors).

When you do `django-admin startproject myproject` you already get prefilled the `TEMPLATES` setting among the others:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': []
    ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

You can see the whole template of `settings.py` file Django is using, in the [github repo of Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/project_name/settings.py-tpl)

Comment: Yeah, but in the past i linked for one project to the official docs "add the [official](link) context processors and 'bla.context_processors.foo'" for a install howto. There now seems to lack any documentation, except from "read the default settings.py".

Comment: Nope, i mean the old docs contained a list, the new ones have one for migration, but there seems to be no official one, possibly intential. Personally i would prefer some option to put only the new context processors in the config and not having to care about the default ones.

Comment: Now I understand your point. But since each time you `./manage.py startproject` a prefilled settings is generated for you, then IMO there is no reason to worry about that. However, maybe you should open a ticket in Django for this. Did my answer helped you at all?

Comment: I am just not sure about the "right" way. When i upgraded my own installation, i needed to search the new defaults (which i.e. replaced "core" by "template") and so needs every user. Should i document just the way from a boilerplate settings.py, should i try to reference docs or even django source or is there some clever solution for the user to put just the needed line somewhere? But a useful thing is, that the generated config with django 1.10 actually contains the default set of context processors, which was not the case in earlier releases.

Comment: Don't forget that every time a new release is out, the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/) underline all the changes (addons and removals). So, every Django developer should aware these and change code accordingly.